# How to allow user to type date with JQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a JQuery DatePicker in my jsp, and I want to allow user to both use DatePicker and type the date.

I read this [API page](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-constrainInput) where I found the `constrainInput` attribute, and I wrote something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
  });

  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
      constrainInput: false
    });
```

But my input text seems to be still in `readOnly` state

Thank you

Comment: `But my input text seems to be still in readOnly state` Are you sure? In you code, you are calling `$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
      constrainInput: false
    });` outside of document ready handler, that could explain it. Anyway, see posted answer, there is no reason to initialize plugin twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Datepicker only once like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
      constrainInput: false
    });
});
```